# does anyone know why my videos wont show up on my website?

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

> I've been making my own website for one of my homework projects and
>   i'm not sure why my videos wont show up when i uploaded them to my
>   domain site. They worked fine in Dreamweaver when i tested them out
>   locally. Here is my website http://zackvivier.com/portfolio.html and
>   here is my javascript code for the video if that helps

```
var myVid;

function init() {
    myVid = document.getElementById('myVideo');
}

function addVideo(whichVideo) {

    myVid.innerHTML = "<source src='video/" + whichVideo + ".mp4' type='video/mp4'/><source src='video/" + whichVideo + ".webm' type='video/webm'/><source src='video/" + whichVideo + ".ogv' type='video/ogg'/><object width='540' height='304'> <param name='movie' value='http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf'></param><param name='flashvars' value='src=http://www.halvas.ca/Outbox/" + whichVideo + ".mp4'></param><param name='allowFullScreen' value='true'></param><param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'></param><embed src='http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' allowscriptaccess='always' allowfullscreen='true' width='540' height='304' flashvars='src=http://www.halvas.ca/Outbox/" + whichVideo + ".mp4'></embed></object>";
    myVid.load();
    myVid.play();
}
```

Comment: Video loads just fine. Refresh your page or check your connection, or disable add-ons or something.

Comment: What browser and version? I am betting IE9.

Comment: it appears you haven't specified the MIME type properly

Comment: really thats weird i checked them in fire fox and google crome on the schools computer and even on my laptop they didnt work. so they play just fine and are able to switch between them?

Comment: I can't get it to display properly in FF17. But I can download it by using its URL

Comment: yea i just went to the page on my iphone and i can play them which is really weird but not using like a computer and view them on any browser

Answer (score 0):

You haven't uploaded all the files to your webserver.

This one is there, so it plays fine in Chrome.
http://zackvivier.com/video/demoreel.mp4

But it doesn't play in Firefox because this one is 404'd:
http://zackvivier.com/video/demoreel.mp4